# Background rendering for cluster in google maps utils

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

To simplify the question I will refer to the [Google Maps Utils library demo project - custom marker clustering activity](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/demo/src/com/google/maps/android/utils/demo/CustomMarkerClusteringDemoActivity.java)

(Link is to directly to the code) 
Comment on line 69 says it all:
// Note: this method runs on the UI thread. Don't spend too much time in here (like in this example).

My project has a bit of heavier rendering and it creates some lags when manipulating the map. I tried moving the code to an AsyncTask but then it only renders the default markers.

I tried moving the code to onClusterRendered() but the maps response even slower.
I guess I can pre-render lots of possibilities to my cluster but that doesn't feel like the best approach

I'm trying to figure out the correct approach to make this run smoothly. Code would be even better

Comment: Weird, no suggestions ?

Comment: Any luck with this yet?  Been running into the same issue and trying to determine how to get around handling things on the UI thread...

Comment: I'm in the same boat. Would love to have a decent answer. Tried using AsyncTask with no luck.

Comment: I used the pre-render approach

Comment: @ShaiLevy, what you mean by "the pre-render approach"? Is your approach capable of handling 5-10k markers? please, help if you can

Comment: My cluster have several possible combination of marker icon .. I calculated all the possible matched and gave them a hash, when the cluster needs the specified combination it already has a drawable ready. The marker count doesn't make a difference, its the amount of unique icon designs

Answer (score 1):

Old issue, but I came here when I had same problem.

I think the issue is that `onBeforeClusterRendered`'s `markerOptions` parameter is a local variable that is discarded during/after rendering.

Instead, keeping reference to the `cluster` parameter allows you to call `getMarker(cluster)` after the icon is loaded, which will return the marker (if it still exists) or `null`. Then you can use `marker.setIcon(...)`.

To avoid temporarily seeing the default marker you can hide the marker until after the icon has been loaded.

This worked well for me, and keeps the map/UI responsive while loading icons.

```
@Override
protected void onBeforeClusterRendered(Cluster<Person> cluster, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
    // Hide default marker, load icon on background thread and unhide.
    markerOptions.visible(false);
    new LoadClusterMarkersAsync(cluster).execute();
}

private class LoadClusterMarkersAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private Cluster<Person> cluster;

    public LoadClusterMarkersAsync(Cluster<Person> cluster) {
        super();
        this.cluster = cluster;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... v) {
        // Load icon...
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
        super.onPostExecute(v);
        Marker marker = getMarker(cluster);
        if (marker != null) {
            marker.setIcon(...);
            marker.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
override fun onBeforeClusterRendered(
        cluster: Cluster<MapItem>,
        markerOptions: MarkerOptions
    ) {
        // Draw multiple items.
        // Hide markers while getting cluster icon
        markerOptions.visible(false)
        // This *must* run on the Main thread
        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            val icon = getClusterIcon(cluster)
            getMarker(cluster)?.apply {
                setIcon(icon)
                isVisible = true
            }
        }
    }

// Run this on dispatcher optimized for CPU-intensive work
private suspend fun getClusterIcon(cluster: Cluster<MapItem>): BitmapDescriptor =
        withContext(Dispatchers.Default) { ...
```